# Control iPhone 6S with keyboard

Tags: iphone, keyboard

My dad dropped his iPhone 6S down the toilet

Luckily it still works, except for the whole of the touchscreen.

He wants to get the photos off, he’s got most of them but for some reason iCloud has left a big gap from September 2017.

I’ve bought a Lightning to USB adapter and plugged a keyboard in and managed to unlock it, but now I can’t go any further.

I can get to the settings app but can’t navigate through it with a keyboard. I can open Bluetooth settings but not enable it, I can long press the home button to receive the prompt to *enable* Siri but not enable it without touching the screen. Same with VoiceOver.

Can anyone recommend a way of controlling the settings without using the touch screen?

Comment: While not intended for this, if you can enable switch controls, you may be able to control it. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201370 - Outside of that, you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to tripple-click the home button, or tripple-click f5 on the keyboard, to enable VoiceOver? I'm thinking that's what the accessibility shortcut is set to by default.
Once VoiceOver is enabled, you should be able to control the iPhone with the [VoiceOver keyboard commands](https://help.apple.com/iphone/5/voiceover/en/iph6c494dc6.html) (turn on quick nav to navigate the iPhone with arrow keys only).